# Run a piece of code repeated inside an action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am trying to give an excel file to the User, which has some basic border and color filling. Instead of writing them again and again, can any one suggest me a better approach.

Here is the sample code i want to repeat multiple times.

```
ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Border.Top.Color.SetColor(Color.Red);
ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Border.Top.Style= ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Border.Left.Color.SetColor(Color.Red);
ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Border.Right.Color.SetColor(Color.Red);
ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Border.Bottom.Color.SetColor(Color.Red);
ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
```

I want to do something like this multiple times in my action method which needs a previous set of values (row,col ie this is of some other excel file). Also I'm writing values into the same worksheet.

I dont want to repeat the code. Please Suggest me a better approach.

Comment: Are you just asking for a `For` loop for `row` and `col`?

Comment: Assign `ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Border` to a variable

Comment: make a function that takes row and col to do these, so it becomes SetBorder(row,col) ..

Comment: Nope, i have a already a loop, I have to do a multiple action such as border colors red or black for wrong and correct values resp. and background yellow and white for important values etc. So I have to write a whole lot of things again and again. Instead if I will be able to call a function kind then it would be better.

Comment: Instead of repeating you should set the style of the entire ExcelRange and not Cell by cell. I am assuming this is Excel.Interop - cell by cell operations are a real performance killer for this.

Comment: @user6144226 I think I diidn't mention my requirement correctly, hope I have cleared it in the above comment.

Comment: @VishalA - It is unclear - you already know you have to write a function/method and reuse it - what's the question? Which detail of writing one eludes you here?

Comment: @VishalA - You should show a [mcve] in your question to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function and pass arguements for the type of style you want the button, pass it the excel sheet, and the area you want it to edit

```
 private void SetValues(int StyleType, var CurrentSheet, int row, int col)
{
    switch (StyleType)
    {
        case 1:
            //add style if its 1 (this could be for important items as you mentioned)
            break;
        case 2:
            //a different style
            break;
        case 3:
            //I'll use your example here to give you more context
            CurrentSheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Border.Top.Color.SetColor(Color.Red);
            CurrentSheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
            CurrentSheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Border.Left.Color.SetColor(Color.Red);
            CurrentSheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
            CurrentSheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Border.Right.Color.SetColor(Color.Red);
            CurrentSheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
            CurrentSheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Border.Bottom.Color.SetColor(Color.Red);


            CurrentSheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
            break;
    }
}
```

Then call the function for each row/column you need to set it on:

```
for(int i = 0; i<500;i++)
{
    if(important)
    {
        SetValues(1, ExcelWorkSheet, i, 1);
    }
    else if(not_important)
    {
        SetValues(2, ExcelWorkSheet, i, 1);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static function and use it anytime you need.

```
static void SetCellStyle(Range cells, Color color, int row,int col)
    {
      cells[row, col].Style.Border.Top.Color.SetColor(color);
      cells[row, col].Style.Border.Top.Style= ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
      cells[row, col].Style.Border.Left.Color.SetColor(color);
      cells[row, col].Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
      cells[row, col].Style.Border.Right.Color.SetColor(color);
      cells[row, col].Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
      cells[row, col].Style.Border.Bottom.Color.SetColor(color); 
      cells[row, col].Style.Border.Bottom.Style= ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
    }
```

You can call it like this:

```
SetCellStyle(ExcelWorkSheet.Cells, Color.red, row,col);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your code use a loop like this:

```
    for (int row = FIRSTROW; i <= LASTROW; i++)
        for (int col = FIRSTCOL; j <= LASTCOL; j++)
            SetBorder(row, col);
```

Where you replace FIRSTROW, LASTROW, FIRSTCOL and LASTCOL with whatever values you want.
Also add this function to your class:

```
    private static void SetBorder(int row, int col)
    {
        var border = ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Border;

        border.Top.Color.SetColor(Color.Red);
        border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
        border.Left.Color.SetColor(Color.Red);
        border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
        border.Right.Color.SetColor(Color.Red);
        border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
        border.Bottom.Color.SetColor(Color.Red);
        border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
    }
```